# Quick Sort algorithm with three way partition

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging, quicksort

I am new to algorithms and was working on implementing the Quick Sort algorithm with a 3-way partition such that it works fast even on sequences containing many equal elements. The following was my implementation:

```
def randomized_quick_sort(a, l, r):
    if l >= r:
        return
    k = random.randint(l, r)
    a[l], a[k] = a[k], a[l]
    #use partition3
    m1,m2 = partition3(a, l, r)
    randomized_quick_sort(a, l, m1 - 1);
    randomized_quick_sort(a, m2 + 1, r);

def partition3(a, l, r):
    x, j, t = a[l], l, r
    for i in range(l + 1, t+1):
        if a[i] < x:
            j += 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        elif a[i]>x:
            a[i],a[t]=a[t],a[i]
            i-=1
            t-=1
    a[l], a[j] = a[j], a[l]
    return j,t
```

It does not generate correctly sorted lists. I found the correct implementation  of the partition code here in Stack Overflow.

```
def partition3(a, l, r):
    x, j, t = a[l], l, r
    i = j
    while i <= t :
        if a[i] < x:
            a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
            j += 1
        elif a[i] > x:
            a[t], a[i] = a[i], a[t]
            t -= 1
            i -= 1 # remain in the same i in this case
        i += 1
    return j,t
```

Can someone please explain to me how the incorrect partition implementation was failing? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not a lot of point in doing `i-=1` inside that `for` loop since `i` will get reset on the next loop iteration. BTW, you should fix your indentation.

Comment: So , in a for loop, i-=1 will not hold the counter i in place?

Comment: No, it won't. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189609/4014959) for a demo I posted a little while ago.

Comment: j looks like it is incremented in the wrong place. Also, if this is a 3 part quicksort, shouldn't the recursive main part of the function call itself 3 times? Your missing `randomized_quick_sort(a, m1 + 1, m2 - 1);`